# what is wrong with the function call

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 php file (function.php, dp.php) in dp.php i call update function as follow

```
include('function.php');
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$db->update('classes', array('level'=> '(CASE WHEN level = 1 THEN 2
                WHEN level = 2 THEN 3
                WHEN level = 3 THEN 4                    
                END)','modifiedTime'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")), 'level IN (1,2,3)');
$res = $db->getResult();
print_r($res);
```

and the update function :

```
     public function update($table,$params=array(),$where){
    if($this->tableExists($table)){
        $args=array();
        foreach($params as $field=>$value){
            $args[]=$field.'="'.$value.'"';
        }
        $sql='UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.implode(',',$args).' WHERE '.$where;          
        $this->myQuery = $sql; // Pass back the SQL
        if($query = $this->myconn->query($sql)){
            array_push($this->result,$this->myconn->affected_rows);
            return true; 
        }else{
            array_push($this->result,$this->myconn->error);
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

the result i always get is 0 ,where it should be 2, 3, or 4.

the actual statement the is working when it is executed phpmyadmin is:

```
    update classes set level = (CASE WHEN level = 1 THEN 2
                WHEN level = 2 THEN 3
                WHEN level = 3 THEN 4                    
                END), modifiedTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) WHERE level IN (1,2,3));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: **warning** it seems like your code is asking for sql injection attacks.

Comment: @george what is your aversion to spaces ?

Comment: "the result i always get is 0 ,where it should be 2, 3, or 4." - please elaborate.

Comment: when i check in phpmyadmin the level is updated to 0 where it should be 2 when it is 1 and 3 when it is 2 and so on

Comment: "$this->myQuery = $sql;" - have you checked what the _actual_ query looks like? If possible, please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37891913/edit) the actual sql statement to your question.

Comment: Debug debug debug. Echo every variables

Comment: i have added the the actual statment which is working when using it phpmyadmin

Comment: That's not the actual statement, or if it is, `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` will not be doing what you think it will. You need to print out `$sql` and see what it's rendering as.

Comment: Side note: your `CASE` statement could be replaced entirely with `SET level=level+1`... and the entire query could just be `UPDATE classes SET level = level + 1, modifiedTime = NOW() WHERE level IN (1, 2, 3)` with no need for any variables in it.

Comment: i tried it to update only one case and it is working also the date is saved, maybe i can not use CASE/WHEN using this function, i would used level= level +1 but there is many other levels and i only need to update these levels (1,2,3) when a button is pressed

Comment: For the last time, print out `$sql` and see what it is. The `WHERE level IN()` bit restricts the query to just those levels. Frankly, I'd ditch your entire homemade database class/functionality and use a proper framework with an ORM, like Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use current_timestamp instead of using date(..) in your db.php

```
    include('function.php');
    $db = new Database();
     $db->connect();
     $db->update('tbl_class', array('level'=> '(CASE WHEN level = 1 THEN 2
                WHEN level = 2 THEN 3
                WHEN level = 3 THEN 4                    
                END)','update_time' => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 'level IN (1,2,3)');
     $res = $db->getResult();
     print_r($res);
```

one more thing to do is to correct you function

```
        public function update($table,$params=array(),$where){
        if($this->tableExists($table)){
        $args=array();
        foreach($params as $field=>$value){
            $args[]=$field.' = '.$value.' ';
        }
        $sql='UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.implode(' , ',$args).' WHERE '.$where;
        $this->myQuery = $sql; 
        if($query = $this->myconn->query($sql)){
            array_push($this->result,$this->myconn->affected_rows);
            return true; 
        }else{
            array_push($this->result,$this->myconn->error);
            return false; 
        }
    }else{
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't going to work. As written, you're using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a (non-existent) PHP constant.